# Python SMTP.login not working

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Hi guys I'm writing a program to send and email from one email to another from the command line. Below is my program so far but I can't seem to get session.login(sender, password) to work. When I get rid of the "Try, except" function I get an error saying "SMTP AUTH extension not available on this server". I'm stuck and need help.

```
import smtplib

sender = raw_input("Please put in your e-mail")
password = raw_input("Email password please")
recipient = raw_input("Please put person e-mail")
message = raw_input("Insert message")

try:
    session = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls
    session.ehlo()
    #having issues with this specific command
    session.login(sender, password)
    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)
    session.quit
    print("message sent :)")
except smtplib.SMTPException:
    print("message not sent :(")
```

Answer (score 1):

You never actually call the function starttls:

```
 session.starttls  -> session.starttls() # add parens to call
```

Less relevant but you also don't call quit `session.quit -> session.quit()`

Answer (score 0):

Please, try [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail). Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer, but I feel like it can help everyone out!

It really provides a lot of defaults: I'm quite sure you'll be able to send an email directly with:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(username, password)
yag.send(to_addrs, contents = msg)
```

You'll have to install `yagmail` first with either:

```
pip install yagmail  # python 2
pip3 install yagmail # python 3
```

Once you will want to also embed html/images or add attachments, you'll **really** love the package!

It will also make it a lot safer by preventing you from having to have your password in the code.

Comment: I tried installing yagmail and got this error message "Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/6m/qyyw1qz94qdc_h0z05szylnw0000gp/T/pip-build-CkeJNF/keyring/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/6m/qyyw1qz94qdc_h0z05szylnw0000gp/T/pip-3EQldH-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/6m/qyyw1qz94qdc_h0z05szylnw0000gp/T/pip-build-CkeJNF/keyring
"

Answer (score 0):

'recipient' must be in list form for this to work.

Try changing

`session.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)`

to

```
session.sendmail(sender, [recepient], message)
```